# Custom Tag for a List in Word Doc

Tags: ms-word, openxml

I am handcrafting the document.xml to generate a word document. I have a requirement where I have to add a custom tag and some custom tag attributes which will be retained when the word document is saved.

Below is a snippet from my document.xml

```
<w:p>
                    <w:r>
                        <w:rPr>
                            <w:sz w:val="20"/>
                            <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
                            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
                        </w:rPr>
                        <w:t xml:space="preserve">Default list</w:t>
                    </w:r>
                </w:p>
                <w:p/>
                <w:p>
                    <w:pPr>
                        <w:numPr>
                            <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
                            <w:numId w:val="1"/>
                        </w:numPr>
                        <w:numFmt w:val="defaultBullet"/>
                        <w:ind w:left="720"/>
                    </w:pPr>
                    <w:r>
                        <w:rPr>
                            <w:sz w:val="20"/>
                            <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
                            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
                        </w:rPr>
                        <w:t xml:space="preserve">Default 1</w:t>
                    </w:r>
                </w:p>
                <w:p>
                    <w:pPr>
                        <w:numPr>
                            <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
                            <w:numId w:val="1"/>
                        </w:numPr>
                        <w:numFmt w:val="defaultBullet"/>
                        <w:ind w:left="720"/>
                    </w:pPr>
                    <w:r>
                        <w:rPr>
                            <w:sz w:val="20"/>
                            <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
                            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
                        </w:rPr>
                        <w:t xml:space="preserve">Default 2</w:t>
                    </w:r>
                </w:p>
```

I have tried wrapping the Default 1 and Default 2 paragraphs with `<w:customXml>` and `<w:customXmlPr>` as shown in the example here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.customxmlattribute(v=office.15).aspx

I have also tried the smartTag. With all those tags, Word document is generated fine and the contents are correct. But when I make changes and save the document and open the contents of document.xml, the tags are gone. Please help me in identifying tags that don't get deleted when word document is saved.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft lost a patent case to drop using custom xml in word - check - https://redmondmag.com/articles/2009/08/12/court-tells-microsoft-to-stop-selling-word-in-us.aspx

So, it is not possible to use custom xml the way you want to use. Your best bet would be to use content controls. Check [Eric White's answer](http://openxmldeveloper.org/discussions/formats/f/13/p/8078/163620.aspx) ([archived link](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s150/sh/ed883088-d247-4a68-8441-3e5617dba372/673c411c0e4164fe94a7cfffb3c4940b)) for the available options.